# Update multiple rows with different columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform a bulk MySQL update where I know only certain columns need to be updated for each row, e.g. row A only "name" changed to "Sue", row B "name" and "address" changed to "Joe" and "Evergreen Terrace", etc. All the columns and data may be different.

Most [multi-row examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query) typically update the same columns for each row, but is there a way for the SQL command to specify only what's changed per row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name, address, telephone)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tim', NULL, NULL),
    (2, NULL, 'America', '000')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name = IF(ISNULL(VALUES(name)), name, VALUES(name)),
    address = IF(ISNULL(VALUES(address)), address, VALUES(address)),
    telephone = IF(ISNULL(VALUES(telephone)), telephone, VALUES(telephone))
```

will work (leaving the `NULL` fields untouched), presuming the `id` field is the primary key and will trigger the `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, although I can't comment on how efficient it would be.

Answer (score 0):

If the new data is in a separate table, you can do a "multi-table" update to transfer the data into the main table.

To handle the "optional" address, it could be `NULL` in the separate table, then use `IF()` or `IFNULL()` or some other conditional code to leave the old value alone.

But I would probably simply create a bunch of separate `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: The source data is from an external source unfortunately.

Comment: Then I would build a temp table with that data, then do 2 updates -- one to transfer all the 2-column data; one to transfer all the 1-column data.